# How can I run dotnet ef database update from the bin directory without the source code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Basically this is a reboot of [EF Core - Running migrations without sources - Equivalent of EF6's migrate.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084260/ef-core-running-migrations-without-sources-equivalent-of-ef6s-migrate-exe) which is an old question.

My scenario is the same - I want to update the database during the deployment phase from the build artifacts. I do not have the source code. I can checkout it, but then how to avoid EF Core from building the code again? The binaries would not be found in the usual location.

Namely, if I checkout the source code, it would be under **\s** whereas the binaries from the artifact are under **<artifact name>**.

So how can I update the database from the deployment stage given these circumstances?

P.S.

I use EF Core 6.0.8

Comment: They don't do this for deployment, usually the scripts put each version in a folder and we create a table or scenario and apply the version automatically with the related tool.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#sql-scripts https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/01/09/creating-first-ci-for-net-core-ef-code-first-in-azure-devops/