# The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, dependency-inversion

I am using .NET Core dependency injection, but when I am trying to get the service in another class, I am getting the 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments' error.

What does this error means? 
I understand that a generic type argument is something like this: GenericInterface<>, and the GetService method does not take the GenericInterface<> as an argument.

Why am I getting this error and how do I solve it?

The interface

```
public interface IService
{
   void Process();
}
```

The class implementing the interface

```
public class Service : BaseService<IConfig, SomType>
{
    public Service(
        ILogger logger : base(logger)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

The BaseService class is an abstract class and it implements the IService interface.

```
public abstract class BaseService<TConfig, TE> : AnotherBaseService, IService where TConfig : IConfig where TE : struct, IConvertible
{
      protected BaseService(ILogger logger): base(logger)
      {
      } 

      ...
}
```

The AnotherBaseService

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
   protected readonly ILogger Logger;

   protected BaseService(ILogger logger)
   {
      Logger = logger;
   }

   ...
}
```

How I registered them.

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
```

How I am getting the service I need.

```
var incoming = serviceProvider.GetService<IService>();
```

NB: I am just getting started with dependency injection, .NET Core and do not know everything about DI just yet. Your answers would be of great help.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The generic [GetService< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method is an extension method. This means you need to have a :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

to allow the compiler to find it.

This method is only meant for *optional* services. It will return `null` if the object can't be constructed, either because the type wasn't registered or because some of its dependencies are missing.

[GetRequiredService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2) should be used when an application can't work unless a service is available. If an instance can't be created, it will throw an InvalidOperationException.

When that exception is thrown, the full exception text will be a *huge* help in finding the actual problem. Exceptions thrown in constructors can appear in the [Exception.InnerException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. The sequence of calls that ended up in an exception being thrown will appear in the [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. Calling [Exception.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return a string that contains *all* of that information for the current exception and any inner exceptions.

Comment: It worked, but I am now having a null exception. Can you please help?

Comment: @Cookie this means that the type wasn't registered or couldn't be constructed. Use `GetRequiredService< T>` if your application can't work with a specific service. If the service registration is missing GetRequiredService will throw an exception explaining the reason. Sometimes it's clear (a service wasn't registered or a constructor threw), sometimes not

Comment: @Cookie to help with your specific case you'll have to post code that reproduces the issue. If you try `GetRequiredService` post the full exception text, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @Panagiotis Kanavos. I found the cause of it, the null exception occurs because a service that is being used by the "Service" has not been registered.

Comment: This worked, thanks. For some reason intellisense wasn't giving me the hint

Comment: Doesnt work for me.

Comment: @Frank `doesnt work for me` isn't very clear. That method is used by every .NET Core developer in one form or another

Answer (score 8):

It means your compiler only has knowledge of the method that takes a type.

You could call

```
var incoming = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IService));
```

or you could add a

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

to make sure your compiler knows the extension method that lets you specify your type as a generic parameter. This might need the package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` to be installed.

Comment: I was starting to write the *exact* same answer, but you were faster :-)

Comment: @nvoigt Thank you, this worked, I am now having a null exception error where I getting the service. Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: Doesnt work for me.\

Comment: @Frank Please open a new question with *details* what exactly is not working in your context. I'm afraid I can do nothing about a comment that says "Doesn't work for me" without knowing any context.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer which is very well explained in the above posts:

```
ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
```

with the use of following namespace which needs to be defined explicitly rather than relying on intellisense

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Also Keep a note there can be mutiple problems if you getting null exception after this:

1. In startup make sure Hostbuilder service is set to ServiceProvider value

   ServiceProvider = host.Services;
2. Other could be the constructor of the T class couldn't resolve the dependency of the Interface being used.

**

> Thanks !  Happy Coding :)

**

Answer (score 0):

**you should use**

```
var incoming = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IService));
```